# Does $\mathbf{N}$ with the reverse divisibility order form a Heyting algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, heyting-algebra

> Consider the nonnegative integers $\mathbf{N}$ with the reverse divisibility order (i.e. $\mathrm{a} \leq \mathrm{b}$ $\iff$ $\mathrm{b} \mid \mathrm{a}$). Is this a [Heyting algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra)?

One advantage of the reverse ordering is that the elements we usually call 0 and 1 in a lattice are really 0 and 1 respectively, rather than vice versa. It may help to instead consider the isomorphic lattice of subgroups or ideals of the group or ring of integers $\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You might want to add the definition of a Heyting algebra to your post so that other people know what you're talking about. Also add the tag "abstract algebra" because then your post will have more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the lattice of subgroups of the infinite cyclic group is relatively pseudocomplemented.

It is easy to check the pseudocomplement $(p^m)\to(p^n)$ is $(p^n)$ if $m<n$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ if $m\geq n$.  So
$$
((p_1^{m_1}\dots p_k^{m_k})\to(p_1^{n_1}\dots p_k^{n_k})) = \biggl(\prod_{\substack{j\\ m_j<n_j}} p_j^{n_j}\biggr).
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the relation of this answer with Heyting algebras?